# Clean inside of bottle (fruit juice)?

Tags: cleaning

I use Bormioli Rocco glass bottles to store water and fruit juice.

The problem with the juice bottles is that pulp residues dries on the inside of the bottle. How can I clean the bottles?

I have tried CLR (calcium lime rust) remover which is basically a powerful acid and that does not work. Suggestions like "[put rice in the bottle](http://tipnut.com/how-to-clean-the-inside-of-bottles/)" and stuff like that are useless. I mean I have tried ACID ok and the stuff is not coming off. Maybe I need to try raw lye? My concern with using an alkaline chemical like lye (sodium hydroxide) is that it might dissolve the glass.

I have considered trying [piranha solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piranha_solution), a powerful and dangerous mixture used by organic chemists to clean glassware, but it requires access to sulfuric acid and highly concentrated hydrogren peroxide which are difficult to get.

------------------------- ADDITIONAL INFO

I notice a lot of the "answers" seem to assume a brush can be used and obviously have no experience with this kind of bottle. Brushes cannot reach into many areas of this kind of bottles, so saying use a brush is not helpful. If I could use a brush, obviously I would not be asking the question.

Comment: Note that what is needed to dissolve various substances can differ greatly. So the acids you've tried could work for some substances, and not at all for others. In other words, going to a stronger acid or lye, could be unnecessary, and you should possibly try a different group of detergents.

Comment: I usually put some baking soda, a little bit of water and shake it well. That's the best you can probably do but it's not the best method as nothing compares to hand cleaning with a sponge. I wouldn't use any acids or dangerous chemicals, why risk so much? It's not worth accidentally losing your eyesight or getting burn scars.

Answer (score 3):

A bottle brush and some baking soda works wonders.

Answer (score 1):

Soaking the bottle overnight will make the pulp soft enough to scrub out easily.

Just fill the bottle with water and leave it on the counter overnight, then clean it however you would normally. You can add a bit of dish soap to the water if it seems like the cleaning is going to be particularly stubborn, but the pulp should just wash out with little to no scrubbing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Put a tea spoon of liquid detergent in the bottle, add a cup or two of hot water, and shake it to mix the water and detergent well. Then fill it up to the top with hot water and let soak for one hour, or two. Passed this time scrub with a bottle brush using the same liquid that was inside the bottle, discard it and rinse.

The heat makes the mixture of soap and water stronger. Don't use hard chemicals, you are risking poisoning yourself.

If you want to use boiling water (I prefer), add it slowly to avoid breaking the bottle in case it be cold.

Answer (score 1):

I put some fine gravel in the bottle with a few ounces of soapy water.  Then put the top on and shake the bottle for a few minutes --- the gravel scrapes away the accumulated guck.  Rinse well and use.

Comment: The gravel can also cause chips and scratches that more dirt can lodge in (if it does not shatter the bottle outright), this may be dependant on the type of glass.

Comment: You are absolutely right --- I did this with a plastic bottle --- I wouldn't try it on glass as it might chip and scratch and even crack the glass.

Answer (score 1):

While you claim that we have little experience with your chosen brand of container, you appear to not have much experience with brushes made for cleaning bottles.

I submit…
 **Lifehack solution #1** for your particular difficulty (and a picture of your bottle would have been helpful as there are a number of different bottle designs from the company you mention. I have a couple of swing-top models, plain and fluted.)
**A Flexible Bottle Brush**: (Here's one of many. They're also made specifically for wine decanters and such glassware. Some are made to reach every nook and cranny of non-disposal medical equipment such as CPAP gear, colonoscope, etc.)

[image: flexible bottle brush]

**Lifehack Solution #2**
When you finish your drink, fill the bottle with a normal dish-soapy solution and clean it *before* it becomes dried with caked-on residue. It's a maintenance technique issue. If you can't clean it, toss it.

**Lifehack Solution #3**
Choose a container shape and material that you can clean more easily. Your chosen brand of bottles makes wide-mouth containers as well as a number of other stylish bottles to hold appropriate kinds of drinks. A pitcher is normally used for dispensing such beverages. There are a variety of them available with and without stoppers. They are easier to fill and to clean than a small-mouth bottle. It's a matter of choice

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with the juice bottles is that pulp residues **dries** on the inside of the bottle.

There's your problem: once the pulp dries, it becomes work to clean it.

The easiest solution would be to wash your bottle right after use, a bottle brush helps getting the particles out.

If for some reason you can't wash it immediately:
Assuming you stoppered / closed your bottle while there was juice in it, you can simply close it again after pouring the juice out and keep the pulp from caking on. Adding a splash of water (if possible) helps, too. Then once you are home, clean as usual.